# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <form>

Tags: reactjs, forms

When rendering this form, I receive the error

`<tr> cannot appear as a child of <form>.`

in the browser console. How do I get rid of this?

```
<form id='works_input_form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <tr className='text-center'>
        <td>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <textarea
              className='form-control'
              id='title'
              rows='1'
              cols='26'
              placeholder='Name'
              required
              onChange={handleTaskChange}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
    
        <td>
          <div className='form-group p-2'>
            <textarea
              className='form-control'
              id='title'
              rows='1'
              cols='26'
              placeholder='Subject'
              required
              onChange={handleSubjectChange}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
```

Comment: Wrap it with a `table`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `tr` tag cannot reside directly other than table and/or tbody, thead, tfoot:

```
<table>
  <tr>
```

Or,

```
<table>
  <tbody> <!-- thead, or tfoot -->
   <tr>
```

Learn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) about the table html markup.